# Facebook sdk - get user's friends using my app on other platforms

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an application registered for facebook, and it has two versions running on IOS and Android. When I trying to receive friends list from Android, I can see only users using Android version of application, and cannot see ios registered friends. Is there a way to see all users of my app, on any platform?

I use standard request to get friends on Android:

```
public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
    Profile profile =getFbProfile();
    if(profile!=null) {
        String userId =profile.getId();
        String request = String.format("/%s/friends",userId);
        new GraphRequest(
                getFbToken(),
                request,
                null,
                HttpMethod.GET,
                new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                        String resp = response.getRawResponse();
                    }
                }).executeAsync();
    }
}
```

I have both app platforms registered on facebook dev site under single application.

Comment: sounds like a bug, if you are really using the exact same app

Comment: You can see everyone that granted user_friends permission. Maybe you don't ask for it on iOS. Or you are using a different app ids in them

Comment: @WizKid, I ask to chck the iOS app permissions and it hasn't requested user_friends Please post that as answer? I'll accept it)